# Upower not working at all 18.04 -> 20.04

Tags: upgrade, power-management, battery, acpi

I notice there is no battery indicator on Ubuntu 20.04 after update from 18.04. "acpi" works on command line but not "upower"

```
$ upower
(upower:67208): UPower-WARNING **: 18:28:34.153: Cannot connect to upowerd: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.UPower: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.UPower': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

```
$ sudo service upower start
Job for upower.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status upower.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

 $ systemctl status upower.service
● upower.service - Daemon for power management
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/upower.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-10 18:22:40 PST; 2min 46s ago
       Docs: man:upowerd(8)
   Main PID: 47470 (code=exited, status=127)

Feb 10 18:22:40 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: Changed dead -> failed
Feb 10 18:22:40 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: Job 8560 upower.service/start finished, result=failed
Feb 10 18:22:40 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: Failed to start Daemon for power management.
Feb 10 18:22:40 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 10 18:24:47 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: Watching D-Bus name 'org.freedesktop.UPower'.
Feb 10 18:24:47 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: Changed dead -> failed
Feb 10 18:24:47 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: D-Bus name org.freedesktop.UPower now not owned by anyone.
Feb 10 18:24:49 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: Watching D-Bus name 'org.freedesktop.UPower'.
Feb 10 18:24:49 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: Changed dead -> failed
Feb 10 18:24:49 linuxlaptop systemd[1]: upower.service: D-Bus name org.freedesktop.UPower now not owned by anyone.
```

There are various questions about the error but no solutions that I'm finding? For example [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1112822-start-0.html) where no solution is given but a suggestion of changing a `PrivateUsers=yes` in some unnamed config
file?

Apparently this is may be something that needs a package update? I have re-installed upower and various other packages through Synaptic with no effect after reboot.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1748997

I see an odd missing library:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/upower/upowerd 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffde53ab000)
    libupower-glib.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libupower-glib.so.3 (0x00007f4dad3ac000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4dad1cb000)
    libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4dad1af000)
    libgudev-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgudev-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4dad1a2000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4dad142000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4dad019000)
    libimobiledevice.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libimobiledevice.so.6 (0x00007f4dacdf5000)
    libplist.so.3 => /usr/local/lib/libplist.so.3 (0x00007f4dacbea000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4dacbc7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4dac9d5000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4dac9cf000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4dac9b3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4dac9ab000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f4dac94b000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f4dac920000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f4dac904000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f4dac8d7000)
    libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f4dac8cb000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f4dac658000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f4dac3f0000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f4dabfac000)
    libusbmuxd.so.4 => not found
```

but there is a libusmbuxd:

```
 $ sudo ldconfig -v | grep mux
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/local/lib' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0 -> libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0.1602.0
    libwebpdemux.so.2 -> libwebpdemux.so.2.0.3
    libwebpmux.so.3 -> libwebpmux.so.3.0.1
    libusbmuxd.so.6 -> libusbmuxd.so.6.0.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32/ld-2.31.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalled the following packages:
gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 (0.99.11-1build2)
upower (0.99.11-1build2)

Installed the following packages:
libusbmuxd-dev (2.0.1-2)
libusbmuxd-tools (2.0.1-2)

Reinstalled the following packages:
libimobiledevice-utils (1.2.1~git20191129.9f79242-1build1)
libimobiledevice6 (1.2.1~git20191129.9f79242-1build1)
libusbmuxd6 (2.0.1-2)
usbmuxd (1.1.1~git20191130.9af2b12-1)

sudo ldconfig

and this seems to have done it after reboot :)

Comment: Can you please paste the complete command you have used to install and reinstall packages? because I am experiencing a similar issue from my end

Comment: @BreakingBad You can find and remove and install the latest version with Synaptic or similar package manager.